# Laravel middleware Auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

good Morning,

I separate my two guards in Laravel. I would like if someone registers via the Guard "club" he can only access the pages within the Route Group "club", otherwise 403 should come.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/', 'TextController@GetStartseite');

Route::get('/info', function () {
    return view('info');
});


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'TextController@GetWelcome')->name('home');

Route::get('/admin/bund', 'BundController@index')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/meinProfil', 'UserProfilController@index')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/meinProfil', 'UserProfilController@update')->middleware('auth');

Route::resource('/meineAusbildung', 'EducationController')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/meineAusbildung/delete', 'EducationController@destroy')->middleware('auth');

//Waffen
Route::resource('/meineWaffen', 'WeaponController')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/meineWaffen/show', 'WeaponController@show')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/meineWaffen/edit', 'WeaponController@update')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/meineWaffen/getTable', 'WeaponController@getTableWeapon')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/meineWaffen/getDisziTable', 'WeaponController@getDisziWaffe')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/meineWaffen/addDiszi', 'WeaponController@addDiziWaffe')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/meineWaffen/delDiszi', 'WeaponController@delDisziWaffe')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/meineWaffen/DisziDrop', 'WeaponController@getDisziDropDown')->middleware('auth');



Route::get('/meineVereine', 'VereinController@index')->middleware('auth');
//Route::post('/meineVereine/{VereinId}/attach' ,'VereinController@addVerein')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/meineVereine' ,'VereinController@addVerein')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/meineVereineDel' ,'VereinController@removeVerein')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/Zeiterfassen', 'RecordShootingTimeController@index')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/Zeiterfassen/waffenDiszi', 'RecordShootingTimeController@getDisziWaffenDropDown')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/Zeiterfassen/store', 'RecordShootingTimeController@store')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/Zeiterfassen/openEntrys', 'RecordShootingTimeController@getopenEntrys')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/Zeiterfassen/show', 'RecordShootingTimeController@show')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/Zeiterfassen/update', 'RecordShootingTimeController@update')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/Zeiterfassen/delete', 'RecordShootingTimeController@destroy')->middleware('auth');


Route::get('/meinSchiessbuch', 'ShootingbookController@index')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/meinSchiessbuch/getTable', 'ShootingbookController@getShootingbook')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/meinSchiessbuch/freigabe', 'ShootingbookController@clubfreigabe')->middleware('auth');
Route::POST('/meinSchiessbuch/update', 'ShootingbookController@store')->middleware('auth');

//Vereine
Route::get('verein/', 'TextController@GetClubStartseite')->name('verein/');

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Club'] , function(){

  /****Club Login Route*****/
  Route::get('verein/login', 'Auth\LoginController@ClubshowLoginForm')->name('club.login');
  Route::post('verein/login', 'Auth\LoginController@Clublogin');
  Route::post('verein/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@Clublogout')->name('club.logout');
  Route::get('verein/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@ClubshowRegistrationForm')->name('club.register');
  Route::post('verein/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->name('club.register');

});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'club']], function() {

    Route::get('verein/home', 'TextController@GetClubWelcome');


    Route::get('/verein/unsereStaende', 'ShootingrangeController@index');
    Route::POST('/verein/unsereStaende', 'ShootingrangeController@create');
    Route::POST('/verein/unsereStaende/delete', 'ShootingrangeController@destroy');

    Route::get('/verein/Schiessbuch', 'ShootingbookController@Clubindex');
    Route::POST('/verein/Schiessbuch/getTable', 'ShootingbookController@getClubShootingbook');
    Route::get('/verein/Genehmigung', 'ShootingbookController@ClubGenehmigung');
    Route::POST('/verein/Genehmigung/getTable', 'ShootingbookController@getClubSBzurFreigabe');
    Route::POST('/verein/Genehmigung/bestaetigung', 'ShootingbookController@clubbestaetigung');

    Route::get('/verein/Profil', 'ClubProfilController@index');
    Route::post('/verein/Profil', 'ClubProfilController@update');

    Route::Get('/verein/Verband', 'VerbandController@index');
    Route::Post('/verein/Verband', 'VerbandController@store');
    Route::Post('/verein/Verband/delete', 'VerbandController@destroy');

    Route::Get('/verein/Mitglieder', 'ClubController@index');
    Route::POST('/verein/Mitglieder', 'ClubController@update');



});

    // Route::get('verein/home', 'TextController@GetClubWelcome')->name('verein/home')->middleware('auth:club');
    //
    //
    // Route::get('/verein/unsereStaende', 'ShootingrangeController@index')->middleware('auth:club');
    // Route::POST('/verein/unsereStaende', 'ShootingrangeController@create')->middleware('auth:club');
    // Route::POST('/verein/unsereStaende/delete', 'ShootingrangeController@destroy')->middleware('auth:club');
    //
    // Route::get('/verein/Schiessbuch', 'ShootingbookController@Clubindex')->middleware('auth:club');
    // Route::POST('/verein/Schiessbuch/getTable', 'ShootingbookController@getClubShootingbook')->middleware('auth:club');
    // Route::get('/verein/Genehmigung', 'ShootingbookController@ClubGenehmigung')->middleware('auth:club');
    // Route::POST('/verein/Genehmigung/getTable', 'ShootingbookController@getClubSBzurFreigabe')->middleware('auth:club');
    // Route::POST('/verein/Genehmigung/bestaetigung', 'ShootingbookController@clubbestaetigung')->middleware('auth:club');
    //
    // Route::get('/verein/Profil', 'ClubProfilController@index')->middleware('auth:club');
    // Route::post('/verein/Profil', 'ClubProfilController@update')->middleware('auth:club');
    //
    // Route::Get('/verein/Verband', 'VerbandController@index')->middleware('auth:club');
    // Route::Post('/verein/Verband', 'VerbandController@store')->middleware('auth:club');
    // Route::Post('/verein/Verband/delete', 'VerbandController@destroy')->middleware('auth:club');
    //
    // Route::Get('/verein/Mitglieder', 'ClubController@index')->middleware('auth:club');
    // Route::POST('/verein/Mitglieder', 'ClubController@update')->middleware('auth:club');
```

I have addes a Middleware "ClubMiddleware" an registered it to Kernel.php routeMiddleware Methode

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Club;
use App\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class ClubMiddelware
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->getUser()->type !== "club") {
            abort(403, 'Zugriff nicht erlaubt');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

```
php artisan route:list
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                    | Name                    | Action                                                                     | Middleware           |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                                      |                         | App\Http\Controllers\TextController@GetStartseite                          | web                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | Zeiterfassen                           |                         | App\Http\Controllers\RecordShootingTimeController@index                    | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | Zeiterfassen/delete                    |                         | App\Http\Controllers\RecordShootingTimeController@destroy                  | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | Zeiterfassen/openEntrys                |                         | App\Http\Controllers\RecordShootingTimeController@getopenEntrys            | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | Zeiterfassen/show                      |                         | App\Http\Controllers\RecordShootingTimeController@show                     | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | Zeiterfassen/store                     |                         | App\Http\Controllers\RecordShootingTimeController@store                    | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | Zeiterfassen/update                    |                         | App\Http\Controllers\RecordShootingTimeController@update                   | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | Zeiterfassen/waffenDiszi               |                         | App\Http\Controllers\RecordShootingTimeController@getDisziWaffenDropDown   | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/bund                             |                         | App\Http\Controllers\BundController@index                                  | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/api/v1/bund                        | api.bund.getBundTable   | App\Http\Controllers\BundController@getBundTable                           | api                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/api/v1/getEduTable                 | api.Edu.getEduTable     | App\Http\Controllers\EducationController@getEduTable                       | api                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/api/v1/getmeinSchiessbuch          | api.SB.getSBTable       | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingbookController@getShootingbook                | api                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                               |                         | Closure                                                                    | api,auth:api         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                                   | home                    | App\Http\Controllers\TextController@GetWelcome                             | web                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | info                                   |                         | Closure                                                                    | web                  |
|        | POST      | login                                  |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                            | web,guest,guest:club |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                                  | login                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                    | web,guest,guest:club |
|        | POST      | logout                                 | logout                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                           | web                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | meinProfil                             |                         | App\Http\Controllers\UserProfilController@index                            | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meinProfil                             |                         | App\Http\Controllers\UserProfilController@update                           | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | meinSchiessbuch                        |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingbookController@index                          | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meinSchiessbuch/freigabe               |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingbookController@clubfreigabe                   | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meinSchiessbuch/getTable               |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingbookController@getShootingbook                | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meinSchiessbuch/update                 |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingbookController@store                          | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | meineAusbildung                        | meineAusbildung.index   | App\Http\Controllers\EducationController@index                             | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meineAusbildung                        | meineAusbildung.store   | App\Http\Controllers\EducationController@store                             | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | meineAusbildung/create                 | meineAusbildung.create  | App\Http\Controllers\EducationController@create                            | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meineAusbildung/delete                 |                         | App\Http\Controllers\EducationController@destroy                           | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | meineAusbildung/{meineAusbildung}      | meineAusbildung.show    | App\Http\Controllers\EducationController@show                              | web,auth             |
|        | DELETE    | meineAusbildung/{meineAusbildung}      | meineAusbildung.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\EducationController@destroy                           | web,auth             |
|        | PUT|PATCH | meineAusbildung/{meineAusbildung}      | meineAusbildung.update  | App\Http\Controllers\EducationController@update                            | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | meineAusbildung/{meineAusbildung}/edit | meineAusbildung.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\EducationController@edit                              | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | meineVereine                           |                         | App\Http\Controllers\VereinController@index                                | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meineVereine                           |                         | App\Http\Controllers\VereinController@addVerein                            | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meineVereineDel                        |                         | App\Http\Controllers\VereinController@removeVerein                         | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meineWaffen                            | meineWaffen.store       | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@store                                | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | meineWaffen                            | meineWaffen.index       | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@index                                | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meineWaffen/DisziDrop                  |                         | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@getDisziDropDown                     | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meineWaffen/addDiszi                   |                         | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@addDiziWaffe                         | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | meineWaffen/create                     | meineWaffen.create      | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@create                               | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meineWaffen/delDiszi                   |                         | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@delDisziWaffe                        | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meineWaffen/edit                       |                         | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@update                               | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meineWaffen/getDisziTable              |                         | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@getDisziWaffe                        | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meineWaffen/getTable                   |                         | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@getTableWeapon                       | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | meineWaffen/show                       |                         | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@show                                 | web,auth             |
|        | DELETE    | meineWaffen/{meineWaffen}              | meineWaffen.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@destroy                              | web,auth             |
|        | PUT|PATCH | meineWaffen/{meineWaffen}              | meineWaffen.update      | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@update                               | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | meineWaffen/{meineWaffen}              | meineWaffen.show        | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@show                                 | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | meineWaffen/{meineWaffen}/edit         | meineWaffen.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\WeaponController@edit                                 | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | password/confirm                       |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm                | web,auth             |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/confirm                       | password.confirm        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm        | web,auth             |
|        | POST      | password/email                         | password.email          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail      | web                  |
|        | POST      | password/reset                         | password.update         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                    | web                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset                         | password.request        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm     | web                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}                 | password.reset          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm            | web                  |
|        | POST      | register                               |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                      | web,guest            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                               | register                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm          | web,guest            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | verein                                 | verein/                 | App\Http\Controllers\TextController@GetClubStartseite                      | web                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | verein/Genehmigung                     |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingbookController@ClubGenehmigung                | web,auth,club        |
|        | POST      | verein/Genehmigung/bestaetigung        |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingbookController@clubbestaetigung               | web,auth,club        |
|        | POST      | verein/Genehmigung/getTable            |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingbookController@getClubSBzurFreigabe           | web,auth,club        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | verein/Mitglieder                      |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ClubController@index                                  | web,auth,club        |
|        | POST      | verein/Mitglieder                      |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ClubController@update                                 | web,auth,club        |
|        | POST      | verein/Profil                          |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ClubProfilController@update                           | web,auth,club        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | verein/Profil                          |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ClubProfilController@index                            | web,auth,club        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | verein/Schiessbuch                     |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingbookController@Clubindex                      | web,auth,club        |
|        | POST      | verein/Schiessbuch/getTable            |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingbookController@getClubShootingbook            | web,auth,club        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | verein/Verband                         |                         | App\Http\Controllers\VerbandController@index                               | web,auth,club        |
|        | POST      | verein/Verband                         |                         | App\Http\Controllers\VerbandController@store                               | web,auth,club        |
|        | POST      | verein/Verband/delete                  |                         | App\Http\Controllers\VerbandController@destroy                             | web,auth,club        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | verein/home                            |                         | App\Http\Controllers\TextController@GetClubWelcome                         | web,auth,club        |
|        | POST      | verein/login                           |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Club\Auth\LoginController@Clublogin                   | web,guest:club,guest |
|        | GET|HEAD  | verein/login                           | club.login              | App\Http\Controllers\Club\Auth\LoginController@ClubshowLoginForm           | web,guest:club,guest |
|        | POST      | verein/logout                          | club.logout             | App\Http\Controllers\Club\Auth\LoginController@Clublogout                  | web,guest:club,guest |
|        | POST      | verein/register                        | club.register           | App\Http\Controllers\Club\Auth\RegisterController@register                 | web,guest:club       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | verein/register                        | club.register           | App\Http\Controllers\Club\Auth\RegisterController@ClubshowRegistrationForm | web,guest:club       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | verein/unsereStaende                   |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingrangeController@index                         | web,auth,club        |
|        | POST      | verein/unsereStaende                   |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingrangeController@create                        | web,auth,club        |
|        | POST      | verein/unsereStaende/delete            |                         | App\Http\Controllers\ShootingrangeController@destroy                       | web,auth,club        |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

My Browser show the errors Message ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I don't really understand the concept yet. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Matthias

EDIT: I have Post the complete web.php

Comment: There is no redirect happening in the code you shared.

Comment: Which Part of Code i need to see, what happens during the Browser call the url? This problem only occours, when my routes for club are in the group for middleware club.